# Create a suggested choice in string options in Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

For example, if I apply my question to this code from the [Discord.JS guide](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html#option-types):

```js
const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('gif')
    .setDescription('Sends a random gif!')
    .addStringOption(option =>
        option.setName('category')
            .setDescription('The gif category')
            .setRequired(true)
            .addChoice('Funny', 'gif_funny')
            .addChoice('Meme', 'gif_meme')
            .addChoice('Movie', 'gif_movie'));
```

This works great, but what if I wanted the choices to be *optional*, without using a select menu? (i.e., the user can pick "Funny", "Meme", "Movie", or pick their own.)

For my use case, I want to suggest common reasons for mutes:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders")

const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("mute")
        .setDescription("Mute/timeout someone!")
        .addUserOption(option => 
            option.setName("user")
                .setDescription("The user to timeout"))
                .setRequired(true)
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName("duration")
                .setDescription("The duration of the timeout")
                .setRequired(true)
                .addChoice("60 sec.", "1")
                .addChoice("5 min.", "2")
                .addChoice("10 min.", "3")
                .addChoice("1 hr.", "4")
                .addChoice("1 day", "5")
                .addChoice("1 week", "6")
        )
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName("reason")
                .setDescription("The reason for the timeout")
                .setRequired(true)
                // add optional choices like "Posting memes in #general", etc., but also let them type their own reasons
        )
```

For some reason, the docs have absolutely no information about these new classes. I can't find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone said on a different platform, autocorrect lets you write your own input anyway. Also, I found the Builders docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/stable/general/welcome

Comment: Yes, the "autocomplete" feature is exactly what you are looking for to achieve what you want. Simply make "Funny", "Meme", and "Movie" autocomplete choices. Then you could also write some code such that, for example, if a user starts typing an "M" it would only display "Meme" and "Movie" to them in the choices (or they could type in something else). For your purpose of suggesting "common reasons for mutes", this works really well, especially if the users starts to type in one of these three optional choices before seeing them in the choice list.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible the way you want to do it. Straight from https://discordjs.guide/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html#option-types/ : [image: Warning about registering slash commands]

Of course, there might be other workarounds that I don't know about.